# Getting access to models collection in Mongoid instead of Criteria object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, criteria, mongoid

Whenever I do:

```
Person.where(...)
```

I get a `Criteria` object. That's understandable. But I couldn't find how do I get access to actual models collection? For now, I have to do this workaround:

```
Person.where(...).map { |person| person }
```

And then query gets executed and I have an array of `Person` objects. Is there an easier method? #all doesn't seem to work, it returns the same `Criteria` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert the Criteria object to an array:

```
Person.all.to_a
```

Comment: Update: I've discovered there's an #entries method that basically is called, when you call #to_a, so one might use it instead too.